# Kate changes inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode, kate

Why does Kate change inode when I change file? For example:

```
ookami@ookami-E7130:~/test$ touch test
ookami@ookami-E7130:~/test$ ln test test1
ookami@ookami-E7130:~/test$ ls -li
total 0
2782182 -rw-rw-r-- 2 ookami ookami 0 авг.   9 00:21 test
2782182 -rw-rw-r-- 2 ookami ookami 0 авг.   9 00:21 test1
ookami@ookami-E7130:~/test$ kate test1
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
ookami@ookami-E7130:~/test$ ls -li
total 4
2782182 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ookami ookami 0 авг.   9 00:21 test
2782185 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ookami ookami 4 авг.   9 00:21 test1
ookami@ookami-E7130:~/test$
```

I've created file `test`, then made hardlink to it - `test1`. Both files have inode 2782182. After that I've opened `test1` with kate and changed it. Now `test1` has inode 2782185. Is this a bug or it has some reason? If it's right behavior, it's imposible to work with hardlinked files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [known bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316240) in Kate, and one that won't be fixed.  (Bug status is RESOLVED WONTFIX)

Comment: Good [comment](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316240#c6) to issue -"Most people would think it bizarre if editing a symlink generated a second copy of the file."
It sure is! I've spent half an hour, trying to understand, what's wrong with my hardlinked files.